# Merging multiple, unaligned data-frames into single pandas data-frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple data-frames with stock prices that I want to align into a single data-frame that contains only the close prices for all stocks.

I would expect all dates from all data-frames to be present in the date-column(index) and "NA" in case there was no close price for a stock on that date.

Example with two data-frames (df1 and df2):

```
In [5]: df1
Out[5]:
            Open   High   Low    Close
Date1
2012-01-05  22.00  22.66  23.11  24.04
2012-01-04  24.04  23.80  23.08  22.16
2012-01-03  22.16  21.27  20.42  21.24
2012-01-01  21.24  22.30  22.52  22.30

In [7]: df2
Out[7]:
             Open   High    Low  Close
Date1
2012-01-07  23.00  21.66  25.11  21.04
2012-01-06  22.00  22.66  23.11  24.04
2012-01-04  24.04  23.80  23.08  22.16
2012-01-02  22.16  21.27  20.42  21.24
2012-01-01  21.24  22.30  22.52  22.30
```

Now I can do

```
In [8]: frame=pd.DataFrame({"df1.Close":df1["Close"], "df2.Close":df2["Close"]})
```

and the result is as expected:

```
In [9]: frame
Out[9]:
            df1.Close  df2.Close
Date1
2012-01-01      22.30      22.30
2012-01-02        NaN      21.24
2012-01-03      21.24        NaN
2012-01-04      22.16      22.16
2012-01-05      24.04        NaN
2012-01-06        NaN      24.04
2012-01-07        NaN      21.04
```

How would I need to change my code to do the same for a dynamic number of data-frames?
Right now, I have 8 data-frames I need to align this way. Is there any way to loop thru a list of data-frames and align them like above - instead of manually tying the data-frame names (something like df[0] to df[7] figuratively speaking)?

Thanks in advance and kind regards!
Dirk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the data-frames in a list (the actual data-frame objects, I mean, not their names) that looks something like this:

```
dflist = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8]
```

then the following code should do what it seems you're looking for:

```
frame = {}
for idx, df in enumerate(dflist):
    n = idx+1  # Since lists are 0-indexed
    name = "df{0:d}.Close".format(n)
    close = df["Close"]
    frame[name] = close
```

You could do this more compactly with a dict comprehension, but in example code I prefer to spell things out more explicitly for ease of understanding. For reference, the dict comprehension would look something like this:

```
{"df{0:d}.Close".format(idx+1): df["Close"] for idx, df in enumerate(dflist)}
```

Comment: Very cool, thanks a lot! With that example, I'm half-way there. Now how would I make that "dflist" dynamic? I won't know up-front how many data-frames I'm going to need - so I guess I'm looking for a way to create a number of data-frames dynamically and then use your code. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Just use standard list-manipulation methods like `append()` -- so for example when you get a new data-frame, do something like `dflist.append(new_df)`.

Comment: I think I'm getting closer. I now loaded the dataframes into a dict where the key is the ticker of the stock and the value is the dataframe with OHLC quotes for the stock. Now I have a dict with 8 key/value pairs. The remaining question is: How do I join the dataframes into one by iterating thru my dict?

Comment: If you iterate through a dict, you get keys: `for key in my_dict: print key`. But dicts also have an `iteritems()` method for producing tuples of `(key, value)`, so you can do `for key, val in my_dict.iteritems()`. Note that in Python 3, `iteritems()` gets renamed to just `items()`, so use the appropriate name depending on whether you're on Python 2.x or 3.x.

Comment: Some of these questions you're asking are covered by the Python tutorial -- have you worked through that yet? If not, it might be of benefit to you. Go to either http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html or http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/index.html depending on whether you have Python 3.x or 2.x.

Comment: rmunn: Thanks for the dict suggestions - that actually did the trick. I'm sure the answer to all my questions is somewhere in a manual and yes, I'm working thru the manuals. I'm just better with learning-by-doing and with your help, I got there. Thanks again.

Comment: `enumerate` takes optional argument `start` eg `enumerate(dfList, 1)` which can shorten the code a bit.